# Android: What Intent Flag to use so undestroyed Activity will not automatically show upon Notification

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications, android-activity

I have 3 Activities

A. MainActivity - just an Activity with a text and button on it

B. SettingsActivity - this will be displayed if the button on (A) is clicked, this initializes  time picker that will send a notification when it alarms

C. DisplayNotification - activity for displaying notification in the status bar, when clicked, it should show A

This is what I want to happen:

1. I launch my application, A will be shown
2. I click the button, B will be shown
3. I set a time for the alarm
4. When the alarm triggers, a notification is shown in the status bar
5. If I click the notification, A will be shown

This is what happens (I have 2 scenarios with different results):

First scenario:

1. After step 3, I tap the back button, A will now be shown
2. Then, I tap again the back button, the onDestroy of A will be called and screen will show the 'home page' or 'desktop' of the phone
3. I wait till the alarm triggers
4. When the alarm triggers, notification is shown on the status bar
5. I click the notification, it launches my app displaying A
6. End of story. This is what is expected to happen

Second scenario: (the buggy one)

1. After step 3, I tap the HOME button, A's onDestroy is not yet called and the latest screen was B
2. The screen shows the 'home page' or 'desktop' of the phone
3. I wait till the alarm triggers
4. When the alarm triggers, notification is shown on the status bar AND B was shown automatically without me clicking the notification on the status bar
5. What I want to happen here is that it should not automatically display B activity.

Am I missing any flags for notification or intent?

Here is the code snippet for Activity B which triggers the alarm

```
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent i = new Intent(this, DisplayNotification.class);
i.putExtra("NotifID", 1);
PendingIntent displayIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getBaseContext(), 0, i, 0);
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, displayIntent);
```

Here is the code for Activity C

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    int notifID = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("NotifID");
    Intent i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    i.putExtra("NotifID", notifID);  
    PendingIntent detailsIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, i, 0);
    NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification notif = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "See activity!", System.currentTimeMillis());
    notif.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    notif.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
    CharSequence from = "Notification from me";
    CharSequence message = "See activity!";        
    notif.setLatestEventInfo(this, from, message, detailsIntent);
    nm.notify(notifID, notif);
    finish();
}
```

I hope someone would help me :)

Thanks!

Edit:

Thanks Chirag_CID! I should have used Broadcast Receiver instead of another Activity. So, instead of extending Activity, the DisplayNotification now extends Broadcast Receiver. This is the onReceive method of DisplayNotification:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.d(TAG, "DisplayNotification onReceive");
    int notifID = intent.getExtras().getInt("NotifID");
    Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    i.putExtra("NotifID", notifID);  
    PendingIntent detailsIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, i, 0);
    NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification notif = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "See the quote of the day!", System.currentTimeMillis());
    notif.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    notif.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
    CharSequence from = "Notification";
    CharSequence message = "See the activity!";        
    notif.setLatestEventInfo(context, from, message, detailsIntent);
    nm.notify(notifID, notif);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I read the whole Question 2-3 times..

Now I want to point to few things up there,

You have made `Activity C` in which you are *creating notification* which will *call MainActivity on it's Click*.

But, When you *set alarm from B* you are passing `intent of Activity C`, Though your code of `C` **doesn't have** `setContentView` method, and Also you have **written finish()** in the end of onCreate() so when Activity C is called through the Alarm set from B, It just call Activity C and set Notification ..but As you written finish() *it ends Activity C and shows Activity B latest from the Stack*.

If You want to cross check..
**Write logs in onCreate(),onPause() and onDestroy() of Activity C**..and you will see the Activity C is created and Destroyed when Alarm triggered.

Solution:
If you don't want to show any activity when you are on Home Screen and Alarm trigger then,
In Activity B where you written pending intent for Activity C..You will need it to **change to call the Broadcast Receiver** and use `PendingIntent.getBroadcast` where its `PendingIntent.getActivity`  and the code you have written in C for notification you will have to **write that in Receiver**...hence none of your activity will be called when the Alarm Trigger.

Happy Coding :)

Comment: Thanks Chirag_CID! I should have used Broadcast Receiver instead of another Activity. So, instead of extending Activity, the DisplayNotification now extends Broadcast Receiver. This is the onReceive method of DisplayNotification: